# Das u-boot customization for MPC8569E based board

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, processor, u-boot

I am beginner in embedded systems and I need some help here. I have a board with freescale MPC8569E processor. We have been using a 256Mb flash till now, with 2 flash chips. The memory map is as follows:
f000_0000 - f7ff_ffff (128Mb)
f800_0000 - ffff_ffff (128Mb)
Now we want to use 512Mb of flash, using 2 256Mb flash chips each, the memory map being:
e000_0000 - efff_ffff (Flash 1)
f000_0000 - ffff_ffff (Flash 2)

From what I understand from reading about modifying u-boot for one's custom board, first
1. I have to modify the LAW configuraiton. So I add the following in board/freescale/mpc8569mds/law.c
SET_LAW(CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE, LAW_SIZE_512M, LAW_TRGT_IF_LBC),
Flash chip is on local bus.
I have set the Macro CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE to 0xe000_0000 in include/configs/MPC8569MDS.h
2. I need to configure the chipselects for the flash

`#define CONFIG_FLASH_BR_PRELIM 0xF0001011`
`#define CONFIG_FLASH_OR_PRELIM 0xF0006FF7`
for CS0
and
`#define CONFIG_SYS_BR1_PRELIM  0xE0001011`
`#define CONFIG_SYS_OR1_PRELIM  0xF0006FF7`

I have read that CS0 should contain the chipselect of the flash containing boot-code/U-boot, so I have configured CS0 for second flash (base-address 0xf000_0000)

3. I configured the Tlbs as follows:

SET_TLB_ENTRY(1, CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE2, CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE2,MAS3_SX|MAS3_SW|MAS3_SR, MAS2_I|MAS2_G,0, 0, BOOKE_PAGESZ_256M, 1),

and

SET_TLB_ENTRY(1, CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE, CONFIG_SYS_FLASH_BASE,MAS3_SX|MAS3_SW|MAS3_SR, MAS2_I|MAS2_G, 0, 1, BOOKE_PAGESZ_256M, 1)

So I have configured the law, configured the chip-selects, configured the tlbs but the console output is a continous line of special chars ������������ , nothing else !!! What Am I doing wrong?

I have attached the snapshots of tlb1, law and chip-selects for the board, as observed after running the uboot and using an ICD (lauterbach) to pause the boot process after a few secs.
[image: TLB]

[image: Chip selects]

[image: Law]

Comment: on your old board, did you have something else mapped in the e000000 - efff fff range? I have a dim memory of working with another Freescale processor/eval board where the memory-mapped register bank was placed in this range. As I recall, there is a register which specifies the base of this bank. If you check the addresses of your a LAW registers, I'd bet they're in this range and the flash is overlaying them.

Comment: Yes, include/configs/MPC8569MDS.h shows
#define CONFIG_SYS_CCSRBAR  0xe0000000
#define CONFIG_SYS_CCSRBAR_PHYS_LOW CONFIG_SYS_CCSRBAR
So you would have to move this, to use 0xE0000000 range for flash.

Comment: Hey guys, Yeah I had taken care of that, I have already used `#define CONFIG_SYS_CCSRBAR 0xD0000000` in the config file. I belive thats all I need to do to relocate the process registers from 0xe000_0000 to 0xd000_0000.

Comment: I have attached a couple of snapshots in my question (edited) from my ICD, the processor configuration registers that are stored in 1Mb region after CCSBAR are OK !! They are not overlaping, Using the ICD I can read them.

Comment: nobody got input? c'mon.